# Alamofire JSON parameter encoding fail with elasticsearch

Tags: ios, swift, elasticsearch, swift4, alamofire

I am trying to make a request to elastic search using alamofire and swift 4. I tried every type of encoding for the json parameters, and the requests still times out. If i put nil paramters the response comes nicely, but i want to build some query parameters.

I tried building my parameters like this:

```
    let jsonString = "{ \"query\": { \"multi_match\": { \"query\": \"param1 param2 alabala etc\", \"fields\": [\"title\", \"description\", \"category\"], \"fuzziness\": 5 } } }"
        let data = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)
        do {
            let params = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: Any]
            print("ParamsJSON: \(params)")
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
```

And also like this:

```
   let params1 = [
        "query": [
            "multiMatch": [
                "query" : "param1 param2 alabala etc",
                "fields" : ["title*2, description*1.5"],
                "fuzziness" : 5
            ]
        ]
    ]
```

Also my alamofire request is here:

```
    let headers = [
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    ]
    let url = "someurl"

    let request = Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: params1, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
    .authenticate(user: "user", password: "pass")
    .responseJSON { response in
        if let data = response.data{
            do{
                let json = try JSON(data: data)
                completion(json)
            } catch {

            }

        }
    }

    debugPrint(request)
```

The url and authentication works because the query works without sending parameters to it. Only when i send parameters alamofire returns Request timed out error.

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Did you try replacing encoding in Alamofire request function `JSONEncoding.default` with `URLEncoding.default`?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't work. From what i've seen url encoding sends the -d paramter of the curl request as the body of the url, whereas i need to send it as JSON

Answer (score 0):

For everybody out there that will be looking for an answer into this. The reason this happened was because GET requests usually don't have a body (It works with cURL, and some server for testing purposes).

So the answer is, you need to change the request from .get to .post.